# How to access camera roll from camera with custom overlay buttons

Tags: ios, camera, ios7

I have a UIImagePicker controller with an overlay of buttons that can flip the camera, take the photo, etc. and I want one of them to access the camera roll. When the button is pressed, I want the camera roll to open up, and when the user selects a photo, it should start the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`. I have this:

```
UIImage *cameraRoll = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cameraroll_icon"];

UIButton *cameraRollButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
cameraRollButton.frame = CGRectMake(250, 0, 48, 30);
[cameraRollButton setImage:cameraRoll forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cameraRollButton addTarget:self action:@selector(accessCameraRoll:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[overlay addSubview:cameraRollButton];

// accessCameraRoll

-(IBAction)accessCameraRoll:(id)sender {

// What do I put here to get camera roll for self.imagePicker?


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the following , and let us know what happens :)

```
-(IBAction)accessCameraRoll:(id)sender {

 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```